# Increase/decrease integer by 50 with javascript and buttons

Tags: javascript, html, button, onclick

What I want to achieve is having a textbox with the value 0 or blank, and a user to be able to input a number. Then i want the two buttons (one + and one -) to increase and decrease the value of the textbox by 50 for each onclick.

this is my html within the body:

```
<input id="decreaseNumber" type="button" value="-">
<input id="textBox" type="text" value="0">
<input id="increaseNumber" type="button" value="+">
```

The javascript:

```
function increaseNumber(){
var increase = 50;
document.getElementById("textBox").value = increase;}
```

Comment: You forgot to post the JavaScript that you tried.

Comment: I sense there is a question coming somewhere but I cannot find it.  Please refer to the [ask] page to help you formulate a (slightly better) question

Comment: 1. Add event handlers to button
2. In both event handlers, get the value of textBox
3. Increase or decrease value based on which button was pressed
4. Set new value to textBox
5. Profit

Comment: yeah, forgot my javascript, Im not exactly sure how to go from here

Comment: Is this all you have? You want to increase / decrease by 50, why do you have 1000?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
decreaseNumber.onclick = function() {
   textBox.value = parseInt(textBox.value) -50
}
increaseNumber.onclick = function() {
   textBox.value = parseInt(textBox.value) + 50
}
```

Also, you can use native html5 feature http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_input_number

Comment: This question doesn't ask for jQuery, so you shouldn't use it in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just attach a click event and function to the inputs.

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/Dfprp/561/

Very basic example

```
function increaseValue()
{
    var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('number').value, 10);
    value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
    value = value + 50;
    document.getElementById('number').value = value;
}
function reduceValue()
{
    var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('number').value, 10);
    value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
    value = value - 50;
    document.getElementById('number').value = value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/brn5eqrr/)

You can simply take the value and increase / decrease depending on the pushed buttons ID

```
var a = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=button]');

for (var i = 0; i<a.length; i++) {
 a[i].addEventListener('click', addorsub);   
}

function addorsub () {
    var b = document.getElementById('textBox');

    if (this.id == 'decreaseNumber') {
    b.value = parseInt(b.value) - 50;
    }

    else if (this.id == 'increaseNumber') {
    b.value = parseInt(b.value) + 50;                                      
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do it using Javascript/jQuery:

```
var value = $("#textBox").val();

$("#decreaseNumber").click(function(){
  value -= 50;
   $("#textBox").val(value);
});

$("#increaseNumber").click(function(){
   value += 50;
   $("#textBox").val(value);
});
```

I also recommend changing the input type to number:

```
<input id="textBox" type="number" value="0">
```

```js
var value = $("#textBox").val();

$("#decreaseNumber").click(function() {
  value -= 50;
  $("#textBox").val(value);
});

$("#increaseNumber").click(function() {
  value += 50;
  $("#textBox").val(value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="decreaseNumber" type="button" value="-">
<input id="textBox" type="number" value="0">
<input id="increaseNumber" type="button" value="+">
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply use html

```
<input type="number" step="50" value="0">
```

also add the **min** and **max** attributes for setting the minumum number that it can go to and vice versa